# How to get Rotation Vector values when my app supports landscape mode only

Tags: rotation, android-sensors, quaternions

I want to use phone's sensors to create a virtual camera for an AR appli ation but my app supports landscape mode only for now. However, if I use Rotation Vector values from Sensor type "TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR" it gives me values with an assumption that phone is in portrait mode. What should I do to get the values for landscape mode ? Also, my end goal is to get a quaternion from this rotation vector.

I'm coming from Unity background so I'm looking for something that would give the same values as unity's Input.gyro.attitude